# To create colors similar to the Foot pressure heat map in android

Tags: android, image, colors

Am creating an app, which changes its color, when the seek bar is raised.
For example, I have an image (similar to the image 1), when the seek bar is raised above 25%, the color should turn as like in the image 2.Till 25%, the image should be like as the image 1.

Actually, the app am creating, is similar to the foot pressure heat map. In foot pressure heat map, user's pressure is taken as an input to change from image 1(which is at normal stage) to image 2. But here, am using simple seek bar to change from image 1 to image 2.

The problem is, i have no idea how to create colors like in the image 2. I was thinking to apply radial gradient. But i don't know to use it properly. Is there any other methods?

[image]

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;





public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    private SeekBar redSeekBar;
    private GradientDrawable mDrawable;


    ImageView img1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        redSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbr);


        redSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);



        redSeekBar.setMax(254);
        // greenSeekBar.setMax(254);
        // blueSeekBar.setMax(254);

        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean touch)
    {

        if(touch) {
            if (progress >= 25 )

                mDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
                        new int[] { 0xFFFF0000, 0xFF00FF00,
                                0xFF0000FF });

            else if (progress <= 100)
                mDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
                        new int[] { 0xFFFF0000, 0xFF00FF00,
                                0xFF0000FF });

            }


        //colors = Color.rgb(redProgress, greenProgress, blueProgress);
        // imageView.setColorFilter(colors);
    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.translate(0, mRect.height() + 10);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(10, 10);
        mDrawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
        //setCornerRadius(mDrawable, 0, 0, r, r);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }





    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }





}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you explain what is the logic behind your color change, please? Also, show what you have tried so far to change the colors. You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Hi! thank you. I have edited the question and i have added the code i tried.

Comment: Does anyone knows about the coloring part?